# Why session returns null in my JSP page?

Tags: jsp, session

When I was learning session, I got into a trouble.
The code is very basical, and there is no errors here, but when i started up the
 project, I always got a null value, anyone else has ever met that?
Here are my codes:

```
a.jsp:
  <body>
    <h1>restore my session</h1>
    <%  
        session.setAttribute("aaaa", "AAAA");   
    %> 
  </body>




b.jsp:
 <body>
  <h1>get my session</h1>
        <%  
            String s =(String) request.getAttribute("aaaa");    
        %> 
        <%=s %>
  </body>
Thanks for giving your advice!
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
session.getAttribute("aaaa");
```

to get the value.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, so shamed for my carelessness

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the top of your jsp

```
<%@ page session = "false" %>
```

And if possible setting session must always on the servlet sides not on the jsp itself.
I'm not good at explaining but i hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your giving solution, although the first answer has pointed out my mistake, your answer also  gives another alternative thinking.